# How to make [home] go to beginning of line instead of beginning of buffer?

Tags: emacs, freebsd

I know there is an existing shortcut to do this but I'd like to have the home key mapped to beginning-of-line instead of beginning-of-buffer.

I tried putting this in my ~/.emacs file but it seems like it is still being overwritten somehow:

```
(global-set-key [kp-home]  'beginning-of-line) ; [Home]
(global-set-key [home]     'beginning-of-line) ; [Home]
```

On that note, if anyone knows where the default keybindings are set when using emacs on FreeBSD I might be able to modify that file if it is overriding my .emacs.

EDIT: I am using FreeBSD 8.2 and accessing it through SSH/PuTTY.

This is my full .emacs file (nothing too crazy as you can see):

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-h ?\C-?)

(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/sam/programs/go/go/misc/emacs/" t)
(require 'go-mode-load)

(global-set-key [kp-home]  'beginning-of-line) ; [Home]
(global-set-key [home]     'beginning-of-line) ; [Home]
```

Comment: This may or may not be related, but what OS are you using? You mention FreeBSD, but it's in a side note, so it's not entirely clear (at least to me) that it's the same as your main question.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Can you try a `.emacs` containing just these two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<home>") 'move-beginning-of-line)
```

Comment: For my FreeBSD 9 system "<home>" does not work, but "<begin>" does.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
(define-key global-map [home] 'beginning-of-line)
```

Your way seems like it should work too.  Another suggestion to help you debug the problem.  Hit C-h k [home] and it should show you what home is bound to and that may also give a clue what is setting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use smart home key like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145291/smart-home-in-emacs/

Complete code:

```
(defun my-smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Move point to beginning-of-line. If repeat command it cycle
position between `back-to-indentation' and `beginning-of-line'."
  (interactive "^")
  (if (and (eq last-command 'my-smart-beginning-of-line)
           (= (line-beginning-position) (point)))
      (back-to-indentation)
    (beginning-of-line)))

(global-set-key [home]     'my-smart-beginning-of-line)
```